# stats.multivariate_normal.pdf - total size of new array must be unchanged

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, covariance

I am not sure why stats.multivariate_normal.pdf is not working.
At the moment I have

```
from scipy import stats
stats.multivariate_normal.pdf(X, meanX, covX)
```

where

```
X.shape = (150, 2)  
meanX.shape = () # just a float
covX.shape = (150,)
```

The error I get is: "total size of new array must be unchanged"

---

Now I tried to follow the answer:

```
meanL = np.float(np.mean(xL))
covL = np.cov(xL)
stats.multivariate_normal.pdf(xL.T, np.full((150,), meanL), covL)
```

I get the following error:

```
LinAlgError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-4c0280512087> in <module>()
  2 meanL = np.full((150,), meanL)
  3 covL = np.cov(xL)
----> 4 stats.multivariate_normal.pdf(xL.T, meanL, covL)
  5 

/Users/laura/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/stats/_multivariate.py in pdf(self, x, mean, cov, allow_singular)
497         dim, mean, cov = self._process_parameters(None, mean, cov)
498         x = self._process_quantiles(x, dim)
--> 499         psd = _PSD(cov, allow_singular=allow_singular)
500         out = np.exp(self._logpdf(x, mean, psd.U, psd.log_pdet, psd.rank))
501         return _squeeze_output(out)

/Users/laura/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/stats/_multivariate.py in __init__(self, M, cond, rcond, lower, check_finite, allow_singular)
148         d = s[s > eps]
149         if len(d) < len(s) and not allow_singular:
--> 150             raise np.linalg.LinAlgError('singular matrix')
151         s_pinv = _pinv_1d(s, eps)
152         U = np.multiply(u, np.sqrt(s_pinv))

LinAlgError: singular matrix
```

Comment: Is the `stats` statement giving the error message?  My guess is that it's the `covX.shape = (150,)` line that's producing the error.  What's the original shape of `covX`?  Why are you trying to reshape it?

Comment: the original covx is 150,150
but using that still gives me the same error "total size of new array must be unchanged"

Comment: So the `size` (number of elements) in that array are 150*150=22500.  Right?  How is that the same as the size of a (150,) array? You may need to experiment with arrays shape and reshape in an interactive session (with the docs at hand).

Comment: the problem is.. what shape of cov do I need in the stats.multivariate_normal.pdf for it to not give me an error?

Comment: What error is the `pdf` function giving you?  Show the stacktrace along with the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the exact error your getting, but dimensions have to match:
mean and covariance need to have shapes (N,) and (N, N). and X must have width N. Some but not all of these requirements may be alleviated by broadcasting. Anyway, the following works for me:

```
>>> X = np.random.random((150,2))
>>> meanX = 0.5
>>> covX = np.identity(150)
>>> print(stats.multivariate_normal.pdf(X.T, np.full((150,), meanX), covX))
[4.43555177e-63 2.84151145e-63]
```

**Update** From the updated Q I suspect you want

```
>>> X = np.random.random((150,2))
>>> 
>>> meanX = np.mean(X, axis=0)
>>> covX = np.cov(X.T)
>>> stats.multivariate_normal.pdf(X, meanX, covX)
array([0.83292328, 0.18944144, 0.37425605, 1.22840732, 0.5089164 ,
       1.78568641, 0.31210331, 0.64079837, 1.05805662, 0.66416311,
       0.77964264, 0.65744803, 0.53025325, 1.22309949, 1.62169299,
       0.84558019, 1.23537247, 0.44383979, 1.45601888, 0.85368635,
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am doing this exactly, but I receive a new error now, which I put in my question